# insertion of multiple row in a Jtable row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I searched a lot, but didn't find any effective solution for my below problem, plz give your valuable suggestion. Thanx in advance.

insertion of multiple row in a Jtable row after click event on first column [+] symbol. Third column is a JTree, which expanded after clicking on first column [+] symbol and the corresponding values of JTree child node need to be inserted in other column(Best, Good,Avg, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways

- put [JTable as Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) to the JTables cell
- `JTreeTable`, `JXTreeTable`, `OutLine API by Netbeans` and non free by `Jide`

Comment: Thanx for your answer. I am trying your suggestion in my application.

Comment: +1 from shameless [`outline`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692) fan. :-)

Comment: I got my exact answer from here http://sandarenu.blogspot.in/2008/02/treetable-in-java-using-swingx.html. Thanx @mKorbel for your suggestion